# How to add an attribute by detecting web or mobile devices in html tag

Tags: html, ipad, safari

I have one video tag in my website

```
     <video id="html_video" style=" width:100%;" muted autoplay id="bgvid">
           <source src="video/newvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
```

Its working fine without controls in web . But in `iPad`  safari is not detecting `autoplay`.  So I added  `controls` attribute to show play button in safari iPad.

code becomes

```
         <video id="html_video" style=" width:100%;" controls muted autoplay id="bgvid">
           <source src="video/newvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
```

Now the controls is available for ios and web. clicking play button plays the video in iPad.

My question, Is it possible to add this `controls` attribute only to safari iPad and in website the the attribute not percent in it?

Appreciating any kind of answers.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded in it by adding JavaScript in the page as follows

For reference

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ){
              document.getElementById('html_video').setAttribute("controls","1");
            }
            else {
              document.getElementById('html_video').removeAttribute("controls","1");
            }               
        });
```

Thank you.